# How to do file copy in maven plugin?

Tags: java, spring, maven

Now I'm writing a maven dependency A, and using this dependency in project B. The file structures of both are:

Dependency A:

[image]

Project B:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is when I run **mvn spring-boot:run** in Project B, the **test.txt** in A's **src/main/resources/files** will be copied into **/WebContent** in Project B.

What I have tried is writing following code in Dependency A:

```
        final File test = new File("files/test.txt");
        final File dest = new File("WebContent");
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(test, dest);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But When I do **mvn spring-boot:run** it said the file doesn't exist.

Comment: because it really doesn't exisits, your directoy is wrong. Depending on your working directory, it should be `"src/main/files/test.txt"` or `"projectA/src/main/files/test.txt"`, also the target file path is wrong, too.

Comment: Hi @glee8e, then how should I write the path. I've no idea how spring distinguish if I'm looking for a file in dependency or in project

Comment: Please refresh, I just edited comment before you commented.

Comment: accessing `src/` is definitely wrong.  OP, I believe the proper way is to access by loading the resource in classpath, instead of using `File`

Comment: why do  you want to copy a resource from one project to another?

Answer (score 0):

Though I wouldn't suggest copying from one project to another. 
Resources even if are same in two projects should be present in each as their own resource to keep it intact.
Also, considering that you are looking for a solution with maven to do so.

Multi-module maven projects can have resources bundled at a common place using the remote resource plugin -

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>bundle</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*.ddl</include>
        <include>**/*.sql</include>
      </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

***Source*** - [Maven Remote Resources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/examples/sharing-resources.html)

---

To copy a resource within a module or to a target directory which are not a part of default layout or in build/resources, you can also use [Maven Resources Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) as

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <!-- here the phase you need -->
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/extra-resources</outputDirectory>
          <resources>          
            <resource>
              <directory>src/non-packaged-resources</directory>
              <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
          </resources>              
        </configuration>            
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```